# Microfrontend with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, micro-frontend

I've 3 projects with Angular and I need to use all of them in another project.
I can use Microfrontend architecture and mono repository but I must add these projects to the sub-application in angular, maybe I use these apps for another project in the future.

how can I add an external app to an angular project with a command or other ways?